# How do I stop a pry.binding conditionally on a symbol or string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pry

I have a `rails` app running and I am placing `binding.pry` within a method that is called a lot.  I want to stop on a specific `string` on `symbol`, but I cannot find the syntax.  Here is my code:

```
  def can?(resource, operation, options={})
    binding.pry
    credentials(options[:as]).each do |credential|
      can = credential.can?(resource, operation, options)
      return can unless can.nil?
    end
    nil
  end
```

I see in the docs about the `break` keyword, but I can't seem to make that work either.  Could someone please show me what the syntax is supposed to be?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can just add an `if`

```
def can?(resource, operation, options={})
  binding.pry if your_condition_is_met
  credentials(options[:as]).each do |credential|
    can = credential.can?(resource, operation, options)
    return can unless can.nil?
  end
  nil
end
```